# How to force alignment of "cases" brackets in an enumerate environment?

Tags: amsmath, cases

I am using the `enumitem` and `amsmath` packages to give the recursive definition of the valuation function $\nu$ for classical first order logic. The way I have it set up, the brackets of the cases are not aligned (due to differences in length of the expressions preceding the cases brackets).

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,label=\alph*)]

\item $\nu(A 
\wedge B) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = \nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\nu(A \vee B) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = 1$ or $\nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\nu(A \rightarrow B) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = 0$ or $\nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\nu(A \leftrightarrow B) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = \nu(B)$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\nu(\forall xA) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if for all $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$;}\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$    
\item $\nu(\exists xA) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if for some $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$;}\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I would like for the brackets to be aligned down the page, ideally without creating too much ugly spacing elsewhere.

Comment: A question about formatting questions: how would I get my $\nu$ to display the greek letter as it does once you compile LaTeX code to a pdf? Relatedly, how do I insert a preview of my MWE?

Comment: We don't use MathJax here, so if you want a nu, copy-paste a nu using your system character map. Previews are inserted by preparing a picture on your local system then uploading it using the 'Insert Image' interface.

Comment: This site doesn't render `LaTeX` code- it would cause a lot of problems, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths . You can post a preview by inserting a screenshot of your document see [Badges for cleaning up](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A trick from [`mathmode`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) (In my version (2.47) it is in section 65.1 on page 113): save the longest left hand side in a box, and then output the left hand sides in a box of that length:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox\lW
\sbox\lW{$\nu(A \leftrightarrow B)$}

\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,label=\alph*)]

\item $\displaystyle\makebox[\wd\lW][r]{$\nu(A\wedge B)$} = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = \nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\displaystyle\makebox[\wd\lW][r]{$\nu(A \vee B)$} = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = 1$ or $\nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\displaystyle\makebox[\wd\lW][r]{$\nu(A \rightarrow B)$} = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = 0$ or $\nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\displaystyle\makebox[\wd\lW][r]{$\nu(A \leftrightarrow B)$} = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = \nu(B)$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
\item $\displaystyle\makebox[\wd\lW][r]{$\nu(\forall xA)$} = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if for all $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$;}\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$
\item $\displaystyle\makebox[\wd\lW][r]{$\nu(\exists xA)$} = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if for some $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$;}\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output image]

Comment: This suggestion fits better within my paper, thanks!

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, where in the MathMode pdf did you find this suggestion? I'd like to read it to understand what you have done a bit better.

Comment: @Dennis I updated the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I would use an AMS alignment rather than an enumerated list.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}


\begin{tagsleft@true}
\renewcommand\theequation{\alph{equation}}
\begin{flalign}
\nu(A 
\wedge B) &= \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = \nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\\
\nu(A \vee B) &= \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = 1$ or $\nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\\
\nu(A \rightarrow B) &= \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = 0$ or $\nu(B) = 1$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\\
\nu(A \leftrightarrow B) &= \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $\nu(A) = \nu(B)$};\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\\
\nu(\forall xA) &= \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if for all $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$;}\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}\\
\nu(\exists xA) &= \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if for some $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$;}\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{flalign}
\end{tagsleft@true}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great suggestion, wasn't aware of this environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, that works like `amsmath`’s `align` environment, only with an `\item`.

#### Packages

- `listliketab`
- `mathtools` for the `cases*` environment (no need for `\text`)

#### Macros

- `\storestyleofextra[<options>]{<environ>}` is like `\storestyleof` just with an optional argument `<options>` that is given to the environment `<environ>`.
- `\nextnum`/redefinition of `\item` that produces the enumeration

#### Environment

- `alignerate` mimics a left-aligned `align` environment, with an `\item`.

#### Disadvantage

Sadly, `\storestyleof`/`\storystyleofextra` and `\storeliststyle{}` do not save the enumeration style. Though a `\alph*)` can easily be mimiced as can seen in the `\nextnum` macro.

It is probably also easy to implement an optional argument for `alignerate` that works like `label=\alph*)`, the `xstring` package does come to mind …

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\newcounter{listliketablabel}
\newcommand*{\nextnum}{\addtocounter{listliketablabel}{1}\thelistliketablabel)}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storestyleofextra}[2][]{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\llt@list@box}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \begin{#2}[#1]
            \item[] \storeliststyle{}
            \end{#2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}\ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
\storestyleofextra[noitemsep,label=\alph*)]{enumerate}
\newenvironment{alignerate}{%
    \begin{listliketab}
        \setcounter{listliketablabel}{0}\renewcommand*{\thelistliketablabel}{\alph{listliketablabel}}
        \renewcommand*{\item}{\nextnum &}
    \begin{tabular}{L>{\(}r<{\)}@{}>{\({}}l<{\)}R}
}{
    \end{tabular}
    \end{listliketab}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignerate}
    \item \nu(A \wedge B) & = \begin{cases*} 1, & if $\nu(A) = \nu(B) = 1$; \\
                                             0, & otherwise.                \end{cases*}               \\
    \item \nu(A \vee B)   & = \begin{cases*} 1, & if $\nu(A) = 1$ or $\nu(B) = 1$; \\
                                             0, & otherwise.                       \end{cases*}        \\
    \item \nu(A \rightarrow B) & = \begin{cases*} 1, & if $\nu(A) = 0$ or $\nu(B) = 1$; \\
                                                  0, & otherwise.                       \end{cases*}   \\
    \item \nu(A \leftrightarrow B) & = \begin{cases*} 1, & if $\nu(A) = \nu(B)$; \\
                                                    0, & otherwise.            \end{cases*}          \\
    \item \nu(\forall xA) & = \begin{cases*} 1, & if for all $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$; \\
                                             0, & otherwise.                              \end{cases*} \\
    \item \nu(\exists xA) & = \begin{cases*} 1, & if for some $d \in D, \nu(A_x(c_d)) =1$; \\
                                             0, & otherwise.                               \end{cases*} 
\end{alignerate}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]