# Left align text in enumerate

Tags: align, enumerate, logic

I wish to left align justifications in mathematical/logical reasoning. I am currently in an `enumerate` tag.

I have:

```
a) p or q by fact(10)
b) r by negation on (a, 10)
c) s by implication(b, 5)
.
.

I would like to turn the above into:

a) p or q     by fact(10)
b) r          by negation on  (a, 10)
c) s          by implication (b, 5)
.
.
```

I would know how to do this without the enumeration of the alphabet going down the left side of the page. I could simply just use an `align` tag.

1. How do I get the above alignment in an enumeration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the list of items need to be breakable across the page boundary? If not, then this can be achieved using a `tabular`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the sentences will be relatively short, you can use a `tabbing` environment and a counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycurrentline}
\def\postNumberForLine{\stepcounter{mycurrentline}\alph{mycurrentline})}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\postNumberForLine\ \= p or q \= by fact (10) \\
\postNumberForLine \> r      \> by negation on (a, 10)\\
\postNumberForLine \> s      \> by implicaiton (b,5)
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{mycurrentline}
\def\postNumberForLine{\stepcounter{mycurrentline}\alph{mycurrentline})}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\postNumberForLine}ccl}
& p or q & by fact (10) \\
& r      & by negation on (a, 10)\\
& s      & by implicaiton (b,5)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The nice thing about a `tabular` environment is that you can use the column directive `p{<dim>}` for the last column to make it a `minipage` of a specified width.

For this particular `tabular` environment, I made both the first and second columns centered.  The last column is left aligned.  Also, I loaded the `array` package.  That allows me to prepend (or postpend) instructions for each row of the table:  this is achieve by `>{<commands}` to prepend.  I also prepended `\raggedright` to the `p` column declaration to avoid hyphenation.

[image]

Here's a slightly different example to illustrate the `p` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcounter{mycurrentline}
\def\postNumberForLine{\stepcounter{mycurrentline}\alph{mycurrentline})}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\postNumberForLine}c>{$}c<{$}>{\raggedright}p{2in}r}
 & p \text{ or } q & This is the disjunction of proposition $p$ and proposition $q$ & by fact        (10)   \\
 & r               &                                                                & by negation on (a, 10)\\
 & s               &                                                                & by implicaiton (b,5)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've done both prepending and postpending of instructions.  For the second column, I've made sure the content is in math mode.  Also, I've loaded the `amsmath` package to allow me to add `\text{ and }` to properly format the `and` in the middle of math mode.

[image]

If your table might have to straddle a page boundary, then you also might want to consider the `longtable` package.

Comment: How do you show the results of your Latex Code? I wish to know so that I can make better questions.

Comment: I upload a `png` file that I've copied from my desktop.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: See [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://goo.gl/59Kig)

Comment: @Werner Is that post still accurate about the file type?  I've noticed recently that I've only been able to upload `png` files.

Comment: @A.Ellett: I just tested in with JPG and it worked fine. I'll have to add something about the possibility to drag-and-drop though. I'll update the post with that information.

Answer (score 0):

The not-so-perfect [`listliketab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listliketab) package.

See also [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88739/16595) to [How to force alignment of "cases" brackets in an enumerate environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88693/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\newcounter{listliketablabel}
\newcommand*{\nextnum}{\addtocounter{listliketablabel}{1}\thelistliketablabel)}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storestyleofextra}[2][]{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\llt@list@box}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \begin{#2}[#1]
            \item[] %\storeliststyle{}
            \end{#2} \storeliststyle{}%\edef\llt@bot@sep@{\the\llt@bot@sep}
%            \begin{#2}[#1]
%              \item[] %\storeliststyle{}\global\llt@bot@sep\llt@bot@sep@
%            \end{#2} 
        \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}\ignorespacesafterend
}
\storestyleofextra[label=\alph*)]{enumerate}
\newenvironment{alignerate}[1]{%
    \begin{listliketab}%
        \setcounter{listliketablabel}{0}\renewcommand*{\thelistliketablabel}{\alph{listliketablabel}}%
        \renewcommand*{\item}{\nextnum &}%
    \begin{tabular}{L#1R}
}{
    \end{tabular}
    \end{listliketab}\hfill\newline
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{alignerate}{>{$}c<{$} >{\raggedright} p{2in} r}
    \item p \text{ or } q & This is the disjunction of proposition $p$ and proposition $q$ & by fact        (10)    \\
    \item r               &                                                                & by negation on (a, 10) \\
    \item s               &                                                                & by implicaiton (b,5)   \\
\end{alignerate}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item $p$ or $q$
\item $r$
\item $s$
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]